# show only the matched search pattern items in the dropdown ajaxToolkit:ListSearchExtender

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a dropdown where I've used ajaxToolkit:ListSearchExtender. The dropdown shows all the values of the list when I insert some text in the search pattern. I want to display only those values in the dropdown that matches the search pattern.

```
<ajaxToolkit:ListSearchExtender ID="toolkit_srch_address" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="listBoxAddress"
    PromptText="SEARCH ADDRESS" 
    PromptPosition="Top" QueryPattern="Contains"
    IsSorted="true">
</ajaxToolkit:ListSearchExtender>
```

Suppose I've a dropdown list ::

```
apple
aloha
alpasian
appyan
banana
bacci
barsa
brittanica
bryan
cactus
caccy
```

Suppose I search for pattern "*ac*" then in the list bacci, cactus, caccy should show.

How can I do this, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No. You'd rather use [AutoComplete extender](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/AutoCompleteExtender), that is designed specifically for that task.